# Trigger for unique pair constraint

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to act like an exception that will not let a unordered pair not be inserted or updated in a dataset twice.

For example given the set {A,B} where A and B are both columns that are primary keys and {A,B} exists in the table, I do  not want to allow the set {B,A} to exist because that relationship is already defined with {A,B}.

Here is my attempt, but it gives `Trigger created with compilation errors.` and also I don't see how to do this against `new` and `old` information.

```
CREATE TRIGGER pair
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON pairing
DECLARE exists_pair NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(COUNT_VAL) INTO exist_pair
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pairing p, pairing p2 WHERE p2.element_one = p.element_two AND p.element_one  = p2.element_two)

    IF exist_pair > 0 THEN
        RAISE SOME_EXCEPTION;
    END IF;
END;
```

Obviously this is not exactly what I want, but it gives an idea. This will instead return 0 every time until a bad entry is made then it will say every entry valid or not is invalid...so it's not what I want but I have no idea how to use `:new` and `:old` in this context.

This has to work for oracle.

Here is a SQLfiddle with an example insert that should fail: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1afb7/1/0

Comment: make `(element_one, element_two)` a unique constraint (I think you already have this) and add a check constraint that `element_one < element_two`.

Comment: What if e1 = B and e2 = A on the first insert?

Comment: there already exists element_one > element_two in the table and it is not a constraint that is wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function based index will work:

```
create unique index unique_pair_ix on pairing (least(element_one,element_two),greatest(element_one,element_two));
```

Btw: Using a row trigger to select from the same table will cause:

```
ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

if you attempt to insert or update more than a single row in a single statement. So you wont be able to use :OLD and :NEW.

Answer (score 2):

> For example given the set {A,B} where A and B are both columns that are primary keys and {A,B} exists in the table, I do not want to allow the set {B,A} to exist because that relationship is already defined with {A,B}.

The most straightforward way of enforce uniqueness is to add an unique index. But a "simple" index will not work:

```
-- This does not help here
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sample_uniq_ab_fn ON SAMPLE (B,A);
```

Assuming `PRIMARY KEY(A,B)`, with this setup, when inserting `(A=1,B=2)` you will simply enforce the uniqueness of `(1,2)` in the primary key index *and* the uniqueness of `(2,1)` in my unique index. This will not prevent the insertion of `(A=2,B=1)` as `(2,1)` is *not* in the primary key index. Nor `(1,2)` in the unique index.

---

Here you need a [function based index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505), as you want *(min(a,b),max(a,b))* to be unique. Something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE (
  A NUMBER(3),
  B NUMBER(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (A,B));


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sample_uniq_ab_fn
    ON SAMPLE (CASE WHEN A < B THEN A ELSE B END,
               CASE WHEN A < B THEN B ELSE A END);

INSERT INTO SAMPLE(A,B) VALUES (10,20) -- OK
INSERT INTO SAMPLE(A,B) VALUES (20,10) -- ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYLVAIN.SAMPLE_UNIQ_AB_FN) violated
```

Comment: I admit your answer is somewhat more verbose - but in what way is it different from my answer?

Comment: @JensKrogsboell To be honest, I didn't even _saw_ your answer when posting mine 3/4h ago. Nor DCookie's one. That's why I was editing just now to explain why that later wasn't correct. I think this is not an issue, they are great chances the OP will accept based on the timestamp.

Comment: Fair enough - and your explanation of the problem is quite nice:)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of thoroughness I will post my answer that I eventually ended up making via trigger, but it does suffer from the error

`ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pair 
BEFORE INSERT ON pairing
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    found_count number;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO found_count FROM pairing 
    WHERE (element_1=:new.element_2 AND element_2=:new.element_1);
    IF found_count = 1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'The pairing already exists');
    END IF;
END;
.
RUN;
```

It was important for me to note that you must run `show errors` in sqlplus to actually see the errors in your trigger when presented with `Trigger created with compilation errors.`